# How to auto upload a file to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I upload a json file to my s3 in easiest way?

Basically there is a json file in a webpage and I want to keep copy it every 5 minutes and upload to my s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set in a VM or your local machine a script with a command "wget path.for.file.json" and run every 5 min with a [cronjob](https://crontab.guru/every-5-minutes), also add to the script the command with [aws CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/es/cli/) "aws s3 cp /path/for/your/json/file.json s3://yourbucket/" and this should do the magic. This will overwrite the previous file, if you want to keep different versions of this json file then I recommend you to additional add a timestamp to the name of your file like this "wget wget -O `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`-file.json www.path.to./file.json"

Comment: thank you so much, so amazon don't have a service for this, do they?

Comment: No, you have to do this manual or I'm not sure if you can use Lambda for that